# postgre could not translate host name "xxxx.xxxxxxx.xxx" to address: nodename nor servname provided, or not known" after install docker desktop

Tags: docker, host

I've tried to modified host, revert it to normal, and so on. But this doesn't change the error. Before install docker, there's no problem. But after install, I've tried to connect to xxxx.xxxxxx.xxx and gives me this error. DO you have any ideas how to solve this? I've tried to modified /etc/host too. I'm on Mac. Really appreciate any help.

Comment: Hi, just after posting this answer, I was able to fix this by copying again the etc/host before (i've backed up the before host, before I modified it.). However, I still don't have any idea how can this happen. Will appreciate if someone can explain this.

Comment: You haven't really provided us with any information that would help diagnose the problem.